# How can I choose value from make.grid in R

Tags: r

How can I choose a value from make.grid in R
for example, I have this table

[image]

this table is called (b)
if I want to choose value b[0.2,0.6] that equal to 0.1368763
How can I do it in R
this code b[0.2,0.6] does not work

Comment: `b['0.2', '0.6']` should work

Comment: Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Questions should be reproducible. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as `df <- data.frame(…)` where … are your variables and values or use `dput(head(df))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the matrix index to call values that you need. For getting 0.1368763, you would use:

```
b[1, 3]
```

Or as @Onyambu suggested, you can use the names in quotes.

```
b["0.2", "0.6"]
```